# How do web browsers find a source map for a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conventions, map-files

The [following article](http://alejandroblanco.com.ar/all-you-need-to-know-about-jquery-source-maps/) explains that in order to find the source map of a JavaScript file such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/), the web browser looks inside the JavaScript code and looks for the line containing the `sourceMappingURL` directive embedded in a JavaScript comment. For instance, the [jQuery 1.9.0 minified](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js) file contains such a directive at the end of a file. However, the more recent [jQuery 1.11.1 minified](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js) distribution does not contain such a directive, but a [jQuery 1.11.1 map file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.map) is also distributed with this (final stable jQuery 1) version. So how does the web browser find the map file for the minified file.

I guess the convention of web browsers looking for the `sourceMappingURL` directive was dropped in favor of following the naming convention of looking for a file of the same name, with `.js` replaced by `.min`. Is this what happened?

According to the documentation for the recently released Firefox Developer Edition, such browser still seems to be looking for the [sourceMappingURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Use_a_source_map) directive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasoning behind dropping source mapping from recent versions is described on the [JQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/)

> This release **does not contain the sourcemap comment in the minified
>   file.** Sourcemaps have proven to be a very problematic and puzzling
>   thing to developers, spawning hundreds of confused developers on
>   forums like StackOverflow and causing some to think jQuery itself was
>   broken.
>
> **We’ll still be generating and distributing sourcemaps, but you will
>   need to add the appropriate sourcemap comment at the end of the
>   minified file if the browser does not support manually associating map
>   files (currently, none do)**. If you generate your own jQuery file using
>   the custom build process, the sourcemap comment will be present in the
>   minified file and the map is generated; you can either leave it in and
>   use sourcemaps or edit it out and ignore the map file entirely.
>
> We hope to bring back and improve sourcemap support in the future, but
>   at the moment neither the design nor the implementation seem suited
>   for situations like jQuery’s, where there are widely distributed files
>   on CDNs. We’d like sourcemaps (and browsers supporting them) to
>   gracefully handle situations like file renaming or missing files. See
>   our bug ticket for more information.

Comment: OK. The feature is lacking from current jQuery implementations due to the development team's dissatisfaction with browser support for source maps. Thanks.

Comment: Well, not really. It's more to do with peoples misunderstanding of sourcemaps and the confusion caused by the 404 message in your console if a sourcemap isn't used. Hence the Stack Overflow reference above.

Comment: What a shame for such a useful feature. I hope this gets fixed sometime soon.